# What do I lose by casting to an object and then back again?

Tags: c#, generics, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have a Windows Phone application I am developing that needs to persist some objects to IsolatedStorage. Isolated Storage is pretty handy in that you can just pop an object into in using a few lines of code.

I need a few more objects persisted where the type is different but the method of persisting is not. What I was going to do was simply cast my types to object, save them and when retrieving them cast back to the particular type needed.

Because of conventions used by the app I always know which cast to perform but I wonder if doing this would cause me to loose anything during the cast / recast of the object.

EDIT: I would like to point out that the comments have showed me that I was actually looking for generics without knowing that they solve my issue. I have upvoted everyone who suggested them as they took apart my question and found the crux of my dilemma. Thanks to all that suggested them.

Comment: "...the type is different but the method of persisting is not." This sounds like a textbook case for a generic method.

Comment: Generics were introduced for this exact situation. E.g. List<Int> vs. List.

Comment: +1 for the Generic route. Here's a blog post demonstrating one way of using generics with Isolated Storage: http://www.basarat.com/2011/05/silverlight-tip-using-isolated-storage.html

Comment: Do you have any links on generic methods? Search generics seem to return results on how to create collections which is not really what I need I think. Edit keyboardp that's exactly I i needed, could you put it as an answer so I can give it a Green Tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics is perfect for this scenario. There's an example of how to create generic methods that read and write to an Isolated Storage [here](http://www.basarat.com/2011/05/silverlight-tip-using-isolated-storage.html).

Comment: Cheers, Although I wont be using that specific implementation it gave me just enough to understand what generic methods are and I now have a much better algorithmic structure for my app :)

Answer (score 2):

If the original type is a value type, then you are performing boxing and unboxing, which is a bit of a performance hit.

Whether the original type is a value type reference type, you are probably losing readability and type safety.

Edit:

This is not what you originally asked, however, to use generics:

Check if there is a IsolatedStorage<T> (IsolatedStorage of T),

If not create one that wraps IsolatedStorage with a generic API.

Comment: True and I have upvoted you in recognition. My appologies, I was not aware of generics but knowing about them now they whitewash my initial question but still answer it in the way it was meant. This is the part of development I like the most.